# Can I copy files from one aws bucket to another aws bucket without downloading to local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some huge files which are in bucket1. I need to copy some of the files to bucket2. I know some ways where I will download files from bucket1 to local machine and upload to bucket2.

Can I skip this download and upload step and request amazon to copy files without downloading? Is this even possible?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/

Comment: Basically you do a copy in such cases not download and upload. It depends upon how you want to do. The above link is by using aws CLI. Similarly if you want to do via SDK (like java sdk or javascript SDK), you can search for the appropriate way of doing copy in specific SDK

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 has API calls that can copy objects between buckets (even between regions), which does not involve any downloading.

The easiest method is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has some useful commands:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket1/ s3://bucket2/
```

will syncrhonize files between buckets, so they have the same content.

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://bucket1/ s3://bucket2/
```

will do similar, but you can be more selective

See: [Using High-Level s3 Commands with the AWS Command Line Interface - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html)